# Creating Image-Control in C++ Win32

Tags: c++, image, winapi, resources

I'm trying to implement a picture-cotrol to my Win32-C++ resource to load multiple different bitmaps into at runtime. As a starting point I used the tool "ResEdit" to adjust the dialog box the control should appear in and added a picture control.

In the resource preview the following line appears:

```
CONTROL         "", 0, WC_STATIC, SS_BLACKFRAME, 221, 14, 274, 214, WS_EX_LEFT
```

When I try to compile this code, the compiler says:

```
Undefined Keyword WC_STATIC
```

But when I right-click on `WC_STATIC` and click on `Definition`, the `commctrl.h` opens, which is includes in the `resource.h` (also I am using multiple other elements out of this header, such as the list and combo boxes)

What is the problem? And more specific, how do I set an image to this control?
The user has to choose an entry out of a listbox, doubleclicks and a dialog appears with some edit controls, static texts, and a picture of the selected product.

Comment: Do any of the Windows Classes (WC) work?  Try WC_BUTTON or WC_LIST.  If none of them work, then you probably need to #include <comctrl.h> after <windows.h>.

Comment: Yeah, I included comctrl before the windows.h. Now I changed the order and it works! Thank you!